# How does this definiton say that $x$ is a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers, first-order-logic

In the book **A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic** we have this question:

> The language of number theory is $$ \mathcal{L_{NT}} ~is~ \{ 0, S, +, \times, E, \lt\}$$ where the intended meanings of the symbols are as follows: 0 stands for the number zero, $S$ is the successor function $S(x) = x +1$, the symbols $+, \times, \lt$ mean what you expect, and $E$ stands for exponentiation, so $E(3,2) =9$
> Assume that $\mathcal{L_{NT}}$ formulas will be interpreted with respect to the nonnegative integers and write an $\mathcal{L_{NT}}$ formula to express the claim that $p$ is prime number.

And in the answer, at the back, the solution given is:

> For any natural number $n$, let $\bar{n}$ be an abbreviation for $\overbrace{SSS...SS0} {n~times}$ and let
> $$
> Prime(x) \equiv \bar{1} \lt x \land \neg (\exists y)(\exists z) [(y+\bar{2}) \cdot (z+\bar{2})=x].$$
> When we read the symbols with the intended meaning, the formula $Prime(\bar{n})$ states that $n$ is a prime number.

I got that $\neg$ meant there "it is not the case that" but what does $y+\bar{2}$ and $z+\bar{2}$ mean? And why their multiplication not simply the multiplication of $y$ and $z$?

If I were to write it, I would go like this:
$$
Prime (x) \equiv \bar{1} \lt x \land (\nexists y)(\nexists z) (x = y \cdot z) \land y \neq x \land y \neq 1 \land z \neq x \land z \neq 1 $$

The problem with my definiton is that I'm unable to express that $x$ can only be natural number, it cannot be a fraction or something. How can I ensure that?

Comment: You don't have to ensure that $x$ is a natural, as the universe of discourse is $\mathbb N$, so this is implicit. Integer division is not even available.

Comment: nitpick: you need to write $\times$ instead of $\cdot$ to stay inside the language.

Comment: Please, when you cite the title of a book, **always** mention its author(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should have written $(y+\bar{2})\times(z+\bar{2})$ instead of $(y+\bar{2})\cdot(z+\bar{2})$. But if you ignore that, they are saying that a number $x$ is composite if and only if it can be expressed as the product of two integers, *both of which are at least $2$*. Think about that for a moment and you will see how it works.

As for your second query, the variables in the language are restricted to non-negative integers. Fractions simply don't exist in this language. So your formula is also a valid definition of a prime number (which can be shortened by removing "$\land z \neq x \land z \neq 1$"). Except that I think it needs brackets around $(x = y \cdot z) \land y \neq x \land y \neq 1$.

Comment: ANother way to define prime, more in line with how it is done in rings, is to define $D(x,y) = \exists z: z \times x = y$ to express that $x$ divides $y$, and then $\text{Prime}(x) \equiv \forall y,z: (D(x,y \times z)) \to D(x,y) \lor D(x,z)$ , the OP's text defines an *irreducible* element of $\Bbb Z$, while this formula defines a *prime* element of $\Bbb Z$. It's a special fact about $\Bbb Z$ that these are equivalent.